# Definition of subjective questions for this site

Tags: discussion

I feel that the *subjective questions* topic that has been omitted from the faq needs to be defined.  It's been addressed by several questions, but I don't see any clear statement reqarding the outcome yet and I believe that is critical at this stage for the site.

I'm really happy that this site exists and is in public beta.  Being a java web developer, I need interaction with the web designers and those more knowledgeable in user experience than I am.  It's a great idea, but I feel that it will be too easy to get lost in discussions rather than address specific issues that is the real purpose of the site. IMHO.

So how does the faq get a definition for subjective questions?  I'm not sure of the process here.

Comment: I think we have to graduate to a full site (which was supposed to be soon) before we can customize our FAQ any more but I'm not sure

Comment: Also FWIW, I think some subjective questions are slipping by that normally wouldn't in part due to the low question volume, It's also a field with many subjective issues so I personally feel bringing down the hammer on otherwise good questions is a very bad idea right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben said, we -- or at least I -- haven't been as aggressive in enforcing the quality of questions lately because we're trying to increase the quantity. The trick is to not let quality dip so low that experts lose interest.

[insert chart here... ]

It's a delicate balance, and we rely heavily on feedback like this to tell us when we've turned the dial too far. Thank you for sharing.

I'll work on expanding the FAQ. Let us know if there's anything specific you'd like to see. For now, I've added the following paragraph.

> If you're familiar with other Stack Exchange sites, questions on UX
>   tend to be a little more subjective than usual. That's okay, as long
>   as the question follows the guidelines outlined in [Good Subjective,
>   Bad
>   Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Okay, here's [another stab at completely writing the FAQ](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/512/the-main-faq-page-doesnt-go-into-much-detail-about-whats-on-and-off-topic/613#613).

Comment: Another important thing is how good Stack Exchange is at making quality very easy to identify. If this were a blog or forum it would be near impossible to tell which posts were good and which were pointless aside from raw view/comments count (which isn't a great measure). Between tags, view counts, "interesting questions," votes and more it's quite easy to tell when a question is great after others have reviewed it.

Comment: Good answer.  I understand the need for balance here.